# Using a variable in a class name?

Tags: php, namespaces

so I have some namespaces defined and I wand to instance new objects like this:

```
$this->controller = new \controller\$this->controller($this->cfg);
```

but I get a

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

How can I make this work?

Comment: This is a very odd problem to have, it is probably better if you were to describe the situation that has led up to this point as finding a solution to *that* problem will be more productive than solving the stated problem. http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to dynamically determine the class name of the object to instantiate. To do this, you can create a variable that contains a string with the class name, and then instantiate on that variable:

```
$string = $someObject->someMethod();
$class = '\\controller\\' . $string;
$newObject = new $class();
```