# What is a good way of associating a Model instance with it's own Class in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm sure there is a common pattern for this kind of thing, and I'm struggling with search terms to find answers, so please bear with me if is this a dupe.

I have a few Classes in my app that create pretty standard Models that are stored in a relational database,  eg;

```
// AtsType::name examples = 'XML', 'RSS', 'SOAP'

class AtsType extends Model
{
    public function ats_instances()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AtsInstance');
    }

    public function import()
    {

    }
}
```

What I need that `import()` method to do, however, somehow invokes a class/interface/contract/whatever based upon the actual model instance. So something like this;

`AtsTypeRss::import()`
`AtsTypeXml::import()`
`AtsTypeSoap::import()`

I'd like them to be standalone classes, in order to eventually use some artisan commands that will generate them for a developer, along with a data migration to create the new model names into the database.

I'm just unsure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like (as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921272/php-variable-in-namespace)), I've searched how to use variable in namespace :

```
class AtsType extends Model
{
    protected $import_method = 'MyMethod';

    public function ats_instances()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\AtsInstance');
    }

    public function import()
    {
        $string = $this->import_method;
        $class = '\\controller\\' . $string;
        $newObject = new $class();
    }
}
```